# Получение чисел от пользователя в aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Как сделать калькулятор с входным числом от пользователя(равно или больше 50 и если меньше 50 то заново попросить ввести число)?

```
@dp.message(Text(" Калькулятор"))
async def with_puree(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(calculatorMess)
    @dp.message(text=(int))
    while int < 50:
        dp.message(Text(int))
        i = int(int)
        if i >= 50:
            await message.reply(calculatorMess2)
    if i >= 50:
            await message.reply(calculatorMess2)
```

Выводит ошибку

```
while int < 50:
^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: а вас к примеру вот это `int(int)` не смутило?

Comment: Оно не выдает ошибку, мне надо получить число из str

Comment: код до туда просто не доходит. Объясните, хотя бы, что зашифровано в вашем `text=(int)`

Comment: когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку калькулятор, название этой кнопки отправляется боту и запускается эта функция, где на любое сообщение бот отвечает что это не число, если в сообщении есть что то кроме цифр, мне просто надо переводить каждое сообщение в int и если оно не переводится либо число меньше 50 то писать введите снова

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя использовать название переменной int, так как это название встроенного класса. Просто переименуй переменную